# A Star search not printing the route

Tags: java, search, a-star

I have attempted to implement A* search as outlined in the pseudo here:

http://web.mit.edu/eranki/www/tutorials/search/

Although the search terminates and finds a goal, my print route() method

```
> private void printRoute() {
        MyNode i = this.getGoalNode();
        while (i != this.getStartNode()) {

            System.out.println(i.getId());
            i = i.getParent();

        }
    }
```

gets stuck in a loop of printing:

```
8
7
8
7
8
7
8
7
8
7
```

I am parsing Open Street maps data to do my search, but I have validated my parse is working with successful BFS and DFS. This is a simplified model I made that is meant to represent a simple grid. I am searching from node 1 to node 12:
1     2     3    4

5     6     7    8

9     10    11   12

so 1 expands to 2 and 5 etc

The closed set when the search completes looks like this:

There must be a flaw in my logic when setting the parent, but I just cannot see it. Would really appreciate any help.

thanks,
MJB

full A* code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class AStar extends Search {

    private LinkedList<MyNode> openList; // This is basically our frontier
    private ArrayList<MyNode> closedList;// This is the visited set.

    public AStar(MyNode startNode, MyNode goalNode, Parser p) {
        super(startNode, goalNode, p);
        openList = new LinkedList<MyNode>();
        closedList = new ArrayList<MyNode>();

    }

    public void Search() {
        openList.add(this.getStartNode());
        while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
            MyNode q = openList.get(0);

            // find the node with the lowest heuristic value
            for (MyNode node : openList) {
                if (node.getF() < q.getF())
                    q = node;
            }
            openList.remove(q);
            ArrayList<MyNode> successors = q.getSuccessors();
            for (MyNode node : successors) {
                node.setParent(q);
                if (isGoal(node)) {
                    System.out.println("search completed- goal found");
                    printRoute();

                    System.exit(0);
                }
                double g = node.getG()
                        + Search.distFrom(q.getLat(), q.getLon(),
                                node.getLat(), node.getLon());
                double h = Search.distFrom(this.getGoalNode().getLat(), this
                        .getGoalNode().getLon(), q.getLat(), q.getLon());

                node.setF(g + h);

                if (openList.contains(node)) {
                    int openIndex = openList.indexOf(node);

                    if (openList.get(openIndex).getF() < node.getF()) {
                        // do nothing.
                    }
                }
                if (closedList.contains(node)) {
                    int closedIndex = closedList.indexOf(node);

                    if (closedList.get(closedIndex).getF() < node.getF()) {
                        // do nothing.
                    }
                } else {
                    openList.add(node);
                }

            }
            closedList.add(q);
        }

    }

    // checks the goal and returns a boolean.
    private Boolean isGoal(MyNode node) {
        boolean toReturn = false;
        if (node.equals(this.getGoalNode())) {
            toReturn = true;

        }
        return toReturn;
    }

    private void printRoute() {
        MyNode i = this.getGoalNode();
        while (i != this.getStartNode()) {

            System.out.println(i.getId());
            i = i.getParent();

        }
    }

}
```

Edit: implemented the changes below (thanks) but still running into the same issue of getting stuck in a loop. Also tried changing the condition on my printRoute() to while(i.getParent()!=null) but once again receiving the same error.

Comment: Could you please provide the following: graph of states for which you are trying to apply your algorithm, start/goal node in this graph, your "path estimation" function?

Comment: Updated, hope that helps.

Comment: What is your heuristic function? Is it a Manhattan distance?

Comment: Its the euclidean distance f=g+h where g = the Euclidean distance of the node from the start and h is the euclidean distance of the node from the goal.

Comment: Can anyone else suggest anything for this? I am still struggling. I have tried implementing my own .equals method in node to assert it is working correctly but I am all out of ideas now.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have incorrect implementation of a node score. A score of a node should be equal to: **path** length from start to this node + **estimation of path** length to the finish. While you implement it like: **estimation of path** length from start to this node + **estimation of path** length from this node to finish.

To implement algorithm correctly you need to store the length of a path that was used to get from start node. So instead of this:

```
double g = node.getG() + Search.distFrom(q.getLat(), q.getLon(),node.getLat(), node.getLon());
double h = Search.distFrom(this.getGoalNode().getLat(), this.getGoalNode().getLon(), q.getLat(), q.getLon());    
node.setF(g + h);
```

You need something like this:

```
node.setPathLen(q.getPathLen() + dist(q, node)); // set actual length of an actual path from start to this node
double g = node.getPathLen();
double h = Search.distFrom(this.getGoalNode().getLat(), this.getGoalNode().getLon(), q.getLat(), q.getLon());
node.setF(g + h); // save estimation of a path to a goal node
```

where dist() - is actual distance between to nearby nodes (1 in your case)

Please see the correct code [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode).

Also few advice:

1. Use priority queue for openList instead of usual list
2. Use hash map to store visited notes (closeList in your implementation)

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'll look at using it. As I understand it, by using the priority queue I could remove the for loop if I used a priority queue as the best node would always be at the head?.

Comment: Implemented your changes but this doesn't solve my problem unfortunately. Still stuck in a loop.